# How to get a number after a specific symbol in bash

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

I have following code. From "-F@" it get the numbers after @. But I have two @ symbols and I wanna to get the numbers after second @ symbol. How can I do that?

```
ip=$(echo $2|awk -F@ '$0=$NF')
```

Comment: Do you understand what that awk script is doing? That is how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$2` contains `12@34@56`, then `56` is the third field.  So, in `awk`:

```
ip=$(echo "$2" | awk -F@ '{print $3}')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. since um new to awk and bash i don't have a in depth knowledge. what i exactly want is to get the ip address part from below line.  muditha5/muditha@05#50@192.168.70.183

Comment: So, if `$2` contains that string, `ip` will end up containing `192.168.70.183`.  Did you try it?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. This is my first question in stackoverflow. it will take some time for me to understand how this works. Highly appreciate your understanding and help.

Comment: I've tried the command in my script and it gave me the below output. "muditha5@05"  it get the numbers right after the first @ symbol.

Comment: That's curious.  I copied and pasted the string from your comment, and ran:  `echo "muditha5/muditha@05#50@192.168.70.183" | awk -F@ '{print $3}'` and the output printed was `192.168.70.183`.  If I'd put that in the `$(…)` command substitution, then `ip` would have been assigned the IP address.  The output you claim you're seeing would require … I was going to say `/` and `#` as the field separators instead of `@`, but you've got what comes before the slash and the first `@` and the characters up to the `#`.  Are you sure that's what you get?  Can you show what you get from `echo "$2"`?

Comment: Thank you so much. your command worked for me :) :) I've spent hours on this. more test | awk -F@ '{print $3}'
192.168.70.183

Comment: When you put the IP address after the program, `awk` interprets it as the name of a file to be processed (which it probably can't find), and it ignores its standard input when given files to process — unless one of the files is spelled `-` (dash) all on its own.